# Global Fluid Variable from Extension Controller?

Tags: variables, typo3, global, fluid

is it possible to create a global fluid variable from an extension controller (without typoscript)?

If yes how?

BR

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with _global Fluid variable_? Do you have an example of an existing one?

Comment: I need to use a variable in my default layout file , 
outside of my extension, but is on the same page

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean or need. Please add more details to your question including code snippets if necessary.

Comment: Ok,
i have an Template like this... Start.html(Template) thats loading a Default.html (Layout) in my base Extension base_template.
Than i have another Extension ext_thinks with own Templates / Controller and many thinks...
Now i need to set a global Fluid Variable in my Controller from ext_thinks to use this in my Template 
base_template->Default.html (this is not a problem with viewHelper and typoscript ) 


Here I thought I had a solution... but failt, its only in my extension context, not global -
$this->view->getRenderingContext()->getVariableProvider()->add('loadOffsetBox', true);

Comment: Just to clear up what may be a half misconception: when a Template references a Layout, that does not mean the Template "includes" or "renders" the Layout, far from it. What it means is that the Template "declares" a Layout that must be used, the rendering engine then renders this by transparently switching the context from Template to Layout before rendering. The important bit here is that nothing you do in the Template will affect what happens in the Layout because the rendering order is Layout-first. Which means, any solution you look for here, must work *independently of the Template*.

Comment: Adding to my other comment: furthermore, it is possible for the same Layout to be used in an MVC and non-MVC context, and in different extension scopes, meaning it isn't always the same approach being used to render the template. Though there are other ways to make for example the same TS available in multiple contexts, my answer below only mentions VH or VariableProvider as ways because those are the only two ways that will consistently work if you override a class or a layout file, respectively. It will then function the same regardless of how the layout is used and rendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, you cannot. You can write a ViewHelper or you can write a replacement VariableProvider to achieve it, but there is no such capability out of the box (neither in Fluid itself, or provided by TYPO3).

Comment: Thanks for your answer  :-(